# Running Apps Script Functions Consecutively

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 apps script functions in my spreadsheet. One inserts a formula into a cell (This formula gives a return based on a 'live' value in other cells. The second changes this formula return to contents only.

When I run these 2 functions separately they give the desired result. (i.e. the value that would be displayed if the formula was still in place.)

But, if I run these formulas consecutively, they return a blank cell.

This is the first function that returns a price based on other criteria:

```
function setPrice() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  cell.setFormula('=ifs(R[0]C[-1]="single",$Q$11,and(or(R[0]C[-1]="twin",R[0]C[-1]="double"),R[29]C[-3]=""),$Q$9,and(or(R[0]C[-1]="twin",R[0]C[-1]="double"),not(isblank(R[29]C[-3]))),$Q$10)');
}
```

This is the second function that changes the returned value to contents only:

```
function valuesOnly() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  cell.copyTo(cell,{contentsOnly:true});

}
```

And here is the code with both functions running consecutively that returns a blank cell:

```
function getPrice() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  setPrice();
  valuesOnly();
}
```

I have tried using a macro to run the first script and then copy/paste manually but this gave the same result:

```
function getPrice() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  setPrice();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

I would like this script to operate as if each function were to run one after the other.

Comment: JS function calls are synchronous, which means they execute line by line. valuesOnly() doesn't get called until setPrice() has finished executing. However, the formula you apply to the range of cells in 'setPrice' is not a part of JS execution stack. There's no guarantee that the range will be populated in time for the 2nd function to copy the computed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.getDisplayValue()`

```
function setPrice() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  cell.setFormula('=ifs(R[0]C[-1]="single",$Q$11,and(or(R[0]C[-1]="twin",R[0]C[-1]="double"),R[29]C[-3]=""),$Q$9,and(or(R[0]C[-1]="twin",R[0]C[-1]="double"),not(isblank(R[29]C[-3]))),$Q$10)');

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  cell.setValue(cell.getDisplayValue())

}
```

If the above code doesn't work please edit your question to include a sample of your data so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (explanations included as code comments) :

```
function getPrice() {
  /** Call first function */
  setPrice();

  /** Send changes made by the previous function to the real spreadsheet */
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  /** Estimated Maximum required time for formula recalculation. Set the time
   * according to your spreadsheet performance
   */
  var milliseconds = 2000;

  /** Wait for recalculation to finish*/
  Utilities.sleep(milliseconds);

  /** Call second function */
  valuesOnly();
}
```

NOTE: The estimated maximum required time depends on you spreadsheet. Spreadsheets having many and/or complex formulas could require more time than other having very few and simple formulas.

Comment: Wasn't aware of .flush
Thanks